# How to check if list contains all Some or None or both with pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

There is a list with type `List[Option[String]]`, it may contain `Some` or `None`

```
val list:List[Option[String]] = List(Some("aaa"), None, Some("bbb"))
list match {
   case /*List with all Some*/ => println("all items are Some")
   case /*List with all None*/ => println("all items are None")
   case /*List with Some and None*/ => println("Contain both Some and None")
}
```

But I don't know how to write it. Is it possible to use pattern matching?

Comment: There are 4 cases, not 3, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write custom extractors:

```
object AllSome {
  def unapply[T](l: List[Option[T]]) = l.forall(_.isDefined)
}

object AllNone {
  def unapply[T](l: List[Option[T]]) = l.forall(_ == None)
}

object Mixed {
  def unapply[T](l: List[Option[T]]) = !AllNone.unapply(l) && !AllSome.unapply(l)
}
```

And use them like:

```
list match {
  case AllSome() => ???
  case AllNone() => ???
  case Mixed() => ???
}
```

Comment: +1, to me this looks like the most elegant and readable solution.

Comment: I think you can short circuit in the failure case. Ex: `object AllSome { def unapply[T](l: List[Option[T]]) = l.find(_.isEmpty).isEmpty
}`

Comment: @wingedsubmariner yep! sorry

Comment: a nice example to use extractor !

Answer (score 3):

One approach involves flattening the list and comparing the resulting length with the original length, like this,

```
list.flatten.length match {
  case 0                      => println("All items are None")
  case len if len < l.length  => println("Contain both Some and None")
  case _                      => println("All items are Some")
}
```

**Update**

To get the contents of each `Some`, simply `list.flatten` , namely for instance,

```
list.flatten
res: List(aaa, bbb)
```

and

```
List().flatten
res: List[Nothing] = List()
```

Comment: Actually, I want to get the content of Some in my real application, so I can't use `flatten`

Comment: @Freewind list.flatten will extract the content of each Some

Comment: But you'd have to `flatten` the list a second time. This also won't detect when the list was empty to begin with.

Comment: alternatively `list.count(! _.isEmpty) match {`

Comment: I prefer a more generic solution, which can detect by item types, not only depend on type feature of `Some` and `None`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a solution with well-defined semantics and based on pattern matching you could do something as follows:

```
abstract class CollectionStatus
case object Empty extends CollectionStatus
case object AllSome extends CollectionStatus
case object AllNone extends CollectionStatus
case object Mixed extends CollectionStatus

object CollectionStatus {
  def default: CollectionStatus = Empty
}

def folder(status: CollectionStatus, o: Option[_]): CollectionStatus = {
  (status, o) match {
    case (Empty, Some(_)) => AllSome
    case (Empty, None) => AllNone
    case (AllSome, Some(_)) => AllSome
    case (AllNone, None) => AllNone
    case _ => Mixed
  }
}
```

Here's how I would use it:

```
List[Option[String]]().foldLeft(CollectionStatus.default)(folder _) //Empty
List(Option("foo"), Option("bar")).foldLeft(CollectionStatus.default)(folder _) //AllSome
List(Option("foo"), None).foldLeft(CollectionStatus.default)(folder _) //Mixed
List(None, None).foldLeft(CollectionStatus.default)(folder _) //AllNone
```

This could be further improved by replacing foldLeft with a tail recursive function that would accumulate the status of the list, and finish its computations without traversing the whole list if it recognized the list was "`Mixed`" already:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
def listStatus(list: List[Option[_]]): CollectionStatus = {
  @tailrec
  def inner(acc: CollectionStatus, ls: List[Option[_]]): CollectionStatus = {
    acc match {
      case Mixed => Mixed
      case s => {
        ls match {
          case Nil => s
          case h :: t => {
            inner(folder(s, h), t)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  inner(CollectionStatus.default, list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val l: List[Option[String]] = List(Some("aaa"), None, Some("bbb"))
l.groupBy({
  case Some(_) => "s"
  case None => "n"
}).toList match {
  case List(_,_) => println("both")
  case List(a) => if( a._1 == "n") println("none") else println("some")
}
```

Comment: Your answers really lacks some explainations.

Comment: groupBy applies the function to all elements in the List generating a key.
It returns a map of the key and list of the elements for the key. So in the example this will return the map:
n -> List(None), s -> List(Some(aaa), Some(bbb))
This is then converted to a List giving a List of tuples (the key and List of Options):
List((n,List(None)), (s,List(Some(aaa), Some(bbb))))
We then pattern match on the List if the List has two elements it must contain None and Some. If the List
only has one element then it is either None or Some and we have an if expression on the key 'n' = None
's' = Some